# opensuse KDE 11.x - How to edit $HOME/.bashrc

Tags: opensuse, kde4

Just install opensuse 11.x kde into my Lennovo X60, kick out the ms window. The must function, input Chinese can't work. When start IBus, it shows following message. How to edit $HOME/.bashrc? Actually I don't know where is $HOME.

Thanks. Forgive my foolishness.

```
IBus 已經成功啟動！如果您無法使用 IBus，請將下列代碼加入到 $HOME/.bashrc 中，並重新登入桌面。

  export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus

  export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus

  export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

IBus startup successfully! If you can't use IBus, pls. add the following code to $HOME/.bashrc, then restart desktop.
     export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus

```
  export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus

  export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

Answer (score 0):

`$HOME` is just an environment variable on your linux installation, you can easily do `echo $HOME` in a console to find out where it points to.
Should be the home directory of your current user.

Tough the question maybe would fit better to http://superuser.com , because it is not really a programming related thing.